# Как принимать и разбирать по UDP QByteArray в структуру из битовых полей?

Tags: c++, qt, сеть, udp

Есть 2 структуры битовых полей объединенные в одну структуру. Раньше, когда общий размер структуры позволял, делал объединение через union в uint64. Сейчас размер структур стал больше, передаю в QByteArray с сервера клиенту и теперь появилась проблема с приемом и разбором.

Как правильно это делают нормальные люди? можно еще с примером, буду рад!

Comment: Приведите пример ваших структур и в каком виде вы их передаете, скорее всего вам надо реализовать некое подобие протокола, т.к. передача сырых данных по сети чревата многими нюансами

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для начала нужно подключить сетевое API в .pro файл проекта, делается следующим образом.

```
QT += network
```

и сразу подключим библиотеку к проекту

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
```

Начнем с передачи. Где-то в классе вы создаете новый сокет.

```
QUdpSocket *socket = new QUdpSocket();
```

Создаем в классе структуру в которое будем класть сообщение.

Структура:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // работает без директив
struct srt_t // размер структуры 160 бит или 20 байт
{
    uint8_t one;
    uint8_t two;
    uint16_t three;
    uint32_t four;
    uint64_t five;
    uint32_t six: 16,
             seven: 16;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Далее вы конвертируете битовое поле в QByteArray следующим образом.

```
srt_t ht{ 255, 255, 65535, 4294967295, 9223372036854775807, 65535, 65535 };

QByteArray arr;
arr.append( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &ht ), sizeof( ht ) );
```

После кодирование битового поля в `QByteArray` можно и отправить наше сообщение, а на этом [сайте](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QUdpSocket.php) можно увидеть более подробный пример, но лучше обратится к официальной [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html) по Qt.

```
socket->writeDatagram( arr , QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 1234 );
```

На этом с отправкой можно закончить. Приступим к чтению нашего сообщения, что бы наша программа приняла наше сообщение, нужно создать `QObject::connect` с сигналом на поступления в буфер данных.

Читаем и декодируем данные из буфера:

```
QByteArray buffer;

srt_t *ht = reinterpret_cast<srt_t *>(buffer.data());
```

Вот и все, данные положили в `QByteArray` и отправили по `udp`, а на другой приняли и декодировали обратно в битовое поле.

Answer (score 3):

Например, вот так оформляю структуру:

```
PACKED_START
struct armos_header_t
{
    unsigned short cmd          :14;
    unsigned short message_type :1;
    unsigned short need_ans     :1;
    unsigned short length       :16;
    unsigned short sender_id    :16;
    unsigned char  error        :8;
    unsigned char  version      :8;
    unsigned short receiver_id  :16;
    unsigned short counter      :16;
};
PACKED_END
```

где

```
#  define PACKED_START _Pragma("pack(push, 1)")

#  define PACKED_END _Pragma("pack(pop)")
```

а потом в полученном по сети сообщении нахожу место начала данных для структуры, и с помощью memcpy копирую в структуру количество байт, равное ее размеру.